# How to center a li>a element in a div?

Tags: css

My code:
http://jsbin.com/yowava/1/edit?output

I've tried everything searched, but the a element in ul>li cannot be vertical-centered in the div.

Sorry for my bad English! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Using your example, the easiest way would be :

```
#menu li {
  line-height:33px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yuxuwibubo/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Set to `line-height` same like `height` of `ul`.

```
#menu li {
   line-height: 33px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try padding , one of the easiest way out.

Just add it to your `nav`

```
  padding-top:10px;
```

Comment: Using `line-height: 33px;` is easier for me :)

Comment: @Mardzis everyone has personal choices

Comment: Thank you. I've found this way but i think is it compatible with multiple platform? I mean responsive. Sorry for my English!

Comment: Yup it works across all platforms. It's fool proof

Answer (score 0):

if u r gonna use the `display:table;` trick u just need this

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 33px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: table;

}
#menu{
    display: table-row;
}
#menu li{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 5%;
    float: right;
}
```

but this doesnt mean that the vertical-align only works with tables ,check @http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/